# Can I combine a list of tokenized strings to a dataframe in R?

Tags: r, list, dataframe, text

I did search, and found several similar questions, but I'm still not understanding this correctly.

I have a dataframe with columns ID, Date, and Text.

```
df <- data.frame(ID = c('1','2','1'),
               date = c('11/12', '11/13', '11/14'),
               text = c('wow amazing', 'test string', 'thank you wow'))
df$text <- as.character(df$text)
```

I then tokenize the text, creating a list of words of each row

```
tokenList <- tokenize_words(df$text)
```

The end goal is to sum up the occurences or types of words for each unique ID.
Example: ID 1 would have a count sum of 2 for the word 'wow', and a sum of 1 for 'amazing'.

I'm thinking I could do this if I could append or insert this tokenized list into my original dataframe, which has valuable info such as ID and Date. 
Or am I thinking of this the totally wrong way?

I see other methods of unnesting the tokenization, meaning each row would contain a single word, and the ID/Date data would be repeated each row for each word.

Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Do you just want to count number of words in `text` ? What is your final expected output ?

Comment: @RonakShah I want to be analyze which words were said the most by which ID's, then ultimately link those with a certain topic, like "gaming". There are 1.3 million sentences in my dataset, so I am leaning against unnesting each individual word

Answer (score 2):

One way of handling this task is to use the tidytext and dplyr packages. You split the words with `unnest_tokens()` then you count how many times each word appeared for each ID using `count()`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidytext)

unnest_tokens(df, input = text, output = word) %>% 
count(ID, word, name = "frequency")

#  ID    word    frequency
#  <chr> <chr>       <int>
#1 1     amazing         1
#2 1     thank           1
#3 1     wow             2
#4 1     you             1
#5 2     string          1
#6 2     test            1
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a base R solution for counting the occurrence of tokens

```
# set ID as names to values in tokenList
r <- unlist(lapply(seq(x<-`names<-`(tokenList,df$ID)),
                   function(k) x[[k]] <- setNames(x[[k]],rep(names(x[k]),length(x[[k]])))))

# form the initial output data frame 
dfout <- data.frame(id = names(r), word = r, cnt = 1)

# sum up occurrence of tokens
dfout <- aggregate(dfout[3], dfout[-3],FUN = sum)
```

such that

```
> dfout
  id    word cnt
1  1 amazing   1
2  2  string   1
3  2    test   1
4  1   thank   1
5  1     wow   2
6  1     you   1
```

Or you can change the last line by `dfout <- unique(within(dfout, cnt <- ave(cnt,word,FUN = sum)))`, such that

```
> dfout
  id    word cnt
1  1     wow   2
2  1 amazing   1
3  2    test   1
4  2  string   1
5  1   thank   1
6  1     you   1
```